# Can't install sbt on Windows XP

Tags: scala, installation, sbt

I tried to install sbt on Windodws XP accord this [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html).

I created `sbt.bat` into `C:\sbt` with contents and `sbt-launch.jar` is in the same sirectory:

```
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar "%SCRIPT_DIR%sbt-launch.jar" %*
```

And now when I run `scala -version` I see:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admintemp>scala -version
'scala' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But `sbt sbt-version` is working:

```
C:\sbt>sbt sbt-version
[info] Set current project to default-d7c225 (in build file:/C:/sbt/)
[info] 0.12.4
```

I couldn't figure out what is wrong here.

- ***How to solve this trouble and install scala correct?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed `sbt`, not `scala`.

You could create a folder with a simple `build.sbt` file and start `REPL` with `sbt console` command.

`build.sbt` content:

```
name := "some-name"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
```

You don't need `scala` installed. With `build.sbt` you could select `scala` version and additional libraries, such as `akka` or `scalaz`.

In case you do need additional `scala` installed you could get `msi` installer from scala-lang.org [download page](http://scala-lang.org/download/).

Comment: Do You want to say that I need download only this scala.jar? Do I need to unzip and install this jar or only unzip?

Comment: @nazar_art: Not `scala.jar`. [`scala-2.10.3.msi`](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.10.3.msi) windows installer. You should install it as any other windows program installer.

Comment: @nazar_art: Note that you don't need `scala` installed. `sbt console` is the best way to start `REPL`.